# How to make view visible to only the item clicked in recyclerview android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am building a music player app.

All songs are displayed in a recyclerview.

On click of any song, I want to:

- Display a view (spectrum/wave) that indicates that the song is currently playing.

This should only be visible to current playing song.

[image]

**RcvLayoutAllSongs.xml**

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_artist_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/artist_name_color"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txt_song_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_song_name"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<es.claucookie.miniequalizerlibrary.EqualizerView
    android:id="@+id/equalizer_view"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:animDuration="3500"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:foregroundColor="@color/bottom_music_stroke"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_song_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

All I want to do is:-

Make **equalizer_view** visible to only the item clicked, and if possible change the color of textview of the item clicked

**SongsAdapter**

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AllSongsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val song = songs[position]
    with(holder) {
        with(songs[position]) {
            binding.txtSongName.text = song.title
            binding.txtArtistName.text = song.subtitle
            //on click
            binding.rootLyt.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.let { click ->
                    click(song)
                    //here I will handle click to display the view on only selected item
                }
            }     
        }
    }
}
private var onItemClickListener: ((Songs) -> Unit)? = null
fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Songs) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
override fun getItemCount() = songs.size
```

The problem with this approach is I also want to make the view invisible when the song is paused..And this is handled in the fragment...Not the adapter

**SongFragment**

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

 binding.pauseView.setOnClickListener {
        //this is where I pause the song when the song is clicked from the adapter, I 
        also want to make the wave/view invisible from the adapter but don't know how
        mainViewModel.pauseSong
    }

  }
```

Comment: Create interface when you click on item, then call removeDataSetChanged(position) in recycler view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onBindViewHolder`, check if that item is the currently playing song, and style it accordingly (font colours, wave image etc).

Make your click listener call some `setCurrentSong()` function that updates which song is the currently playing one, and make that call `notifyDataSetChanged` to make the `RecyclerView` update the items (which will call `onBindViewHolder` again).

The nice thing here is you can call this function from other places too, like when the fragment is first being set up, so you don't need a click to set the current song state. Just keep a reference to your `Adapter` and call `adapter.setCurrentSong` - plays nice with `ViewModel`s etc! Keeps the logic out of the UI

---

You can take the same approach with your pausing - add a `setPaused(Boolean)` function on your adapter. When you pause or start playback, call that function, which sets a `paused` state and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Make your `onBindViewHolder` check whether it's `paused` or not when deciding whether to display the image.

You could also use a property with a setter if you like:

```
var paused: Boolean = false
set(value) {
    field = value
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

or a `Delegates.observable` - basically you just need to make sure the `RecyclerView` gets notified that it needs to update, whenever the value changes.

---

oh, if `mainViewModel` actually holds things like player state, and you have things like a `LiveData` that holds a `paused` state, one that holds a `currentSongId` or whatever, then you'd typically wire it up like this:

```
viewModel.currentSong -> observer -> calls adapter.setCurrentSong
recyclerView.item -> click -> calls viewModel.setCurrentSong
```

That way, the UI (the `RecyclerView`) responds to changes in the state, as described by the VM. When it pushes an event (like a song change) it just sets that *on the view model* because that's where the state is held. And when that state changes, the observer will run and update the UI. It's like a roundabout way of doing things, instead of the `RecyclerView` updating itself directly, but it can be cleaner and easier to reason about once you get your head around it! You don't need to worry about where the event is coming from, because it's always coming from the VM

Comment: Thank you. Its working but I have a problem....

1. When I click on an Item, the equalizer_view becomes visible to the current playing song (as it should) but when I scroll down..The item at position 13 also has thesame equalizer view...E.g I play song at position 0, song at position 13 also gets thesame equalizer view (visible) and subsequent items..

Comment: Here is a link to current behaviour

https://ibb.co/dD5YHPL

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing the code, but it looks like your ``onBindViewHolder`` code sets that styling when it's the current song, but it doesn't *remove* it when it's not. Those ``ViewHolder``s get reused (recycled!) to display items, so you need to set each one up fresh. Your code needs to go ``textColor = if (isCurrentSong) WHITE else BLUE``, ``imageView.visibility = if (isCurrentSong) VISIBLE else INVISIBLE`` etc, so it's getting set with one styling or the other. Looks good btw!

Comment: Genius cactustictacs. Thank you works well!!.
How can I reach out to you via maybe email/twitter??

Comment: Oh I don't give out personal info, sorry!